# Cement porch removal

Tags: removal, cement, slab

We are planning on removing a cement porch from our house, which has a room underneath it. My husband did this to my parents house, using a sledgehammer, but he was 35 years younger. He has some type of saw he said he will be able to use to cut through the cement. We're not taking this lightly, we've been planning this for at least 20 years. He kinda knows his stuff, so I don't doubt him. I was just wondering if anyone had any ideas about making this easier on him. We have a friend with excavating equipment but he doesn't think he can lift the slab without doing damage.

Comment: Just to be clear, are you filling in the room below, or do you want to keep that as a room after demo?

Comment: Jackhammers can be rented. Unless the saw is something akin to what road repair crews use, which very few people own, sawing could be not much less work than using a sledge, with the added bonus of huge billows of lung-destroying dust.

Comment: @kreemoweet   35 years later I know I would probably rent a person with a jackhammer, instead of just the jackhammer.

Comment: If friendly with some of the young whipple snappers in the neighbourhood, a case of two-four might help with the labour.

Comment: If your plan is to let the rubble fall into the room and stay there, that might be fun but otherwise IMO nothing about this is a DIY job for one person with concerns about stamina.  Nvm the saw, how is he going to get rid of the debris?  Continue hammering the chunks until they are within his lifting range then carry them one by one to a dumpster or a pile in the yard?  I'm sore just writing that.  Maybe you'll rent a small excavator with a claw to help?  But you're rentals will start to add up.

Comment: @crip659 All's well until you have a jobsite injury and find that you're responsible to pay for the whipple-snapper that got stupid around big hunks of concrete but isn't covered by their own insurance. That is one of the reasons to hire pros with their own insurance for that, and the damage they may cause to your house if they screw up, neither of which the local beverage-fueled help has.

Comment: Thanks for all the input! I know he talked about a jackhammer before, but I'll have to mention that to him again. I'm not sure what happened with that idea. We are not filing in the room below - that will still be my laundry room. The porch was poured over decking, so he said it won't fall below, but just to be cautious, I'm emptying the room. It will have a complete renovation.